# Eclipse: Separate window for Console and Outline, which don't come up when main Window gets Focus

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 on two screens. I have the main window with editor and navigator on the main screen, while outline and console are in two separate windows on the second screen.

When I focus the main window, the two separate also come up. And this is the point: I want to focus the two separate windows manually, when I need them.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with simple "detached" views like you're describing. But you can use Window > New Window to open a second Eclipse Workbench window, drag that to your second monitor, then configure it with whatever Views as you please. The two windows are focused independently (at least on OS X they are, I don't have Windows or Linux to test with).

Comment: It does work on Windows and Linux. Problem: The editor state is independent for separate windows. This means you would have to select the same class/file in the second window or switch to it there, you can't link view contents like it works in the same window with detached views.

Comment: Would this configuration just work again after restart or do you have to open a second window after every start?

Comment: If you close Eclipse by using the `Exit` menu item the window states are saved and restored; obviously not when you close window after window.

Answer (score 1):

No. Those are dependent palette windows, their focus is tied to the main window.

What you can do: Copy your perspective, close the two views in the copy and switch between the perspectives when you need or want to hide the separate views.

That's how I do it. Two perspectives, one compact when I need the second screen completely, one verbose when I concentrate on the code alone.

Comment: I just managed it by minimizing those palette windows, but a separate perspective would do the same ;)

Comment: Ok... I can't do this, I don't have minimize controls at the palette windows (when using Windows) and the palette windows don't have entries in the window list.